# Using javascript to change :target using a slider's thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

How can I get the values of 'data-room' from these links

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><a href="#" data-room="1" data-slide="1"><img src="images/image-1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-room="2" data-slide="2"><img src="images/image-2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-room="3" data-slide="3"><img src="images/image-3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-room="4" data-slide="4"><img src="images/image-4.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

then add it after the #?

```
jQuery('.thumbs a').click(function () {
  window.location.href = '#';
});
```

The html is for the thumbnails of a slider, the slides change by clicking on one of them.

What I'd like to do is have the url change target accordingly thus switching 'tabs' in the site. eg.: site.html#room1 would make the div with the id 'room1' appear. (that part is already done. I'm just confused with the javascript part).

Hope you can understand it.

Comment: try adding li in the jquery `jQuery('.thumbs li a')`

Comment: @Billy It wouldn't change anything in this case.

Comment: is it all links on the page ? I just tried $("[href]") and it worked on all links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply tweak your event listener to this:

```
$('.thumbs a').on('click', function() {
    var $hash = $(this).attr('data-room');

    window.location.href = '#' + $hash;
});
```

Hope that helps

PS: try to use the [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you are using a recent copy of jQuery

Comment: Better to use `$(this).data('room')`, makes more sense nowadays!

Comment: mh yes convenient but no different really. I take your point though. As of jQuery 1.6 apparently... :)

Comment: Ho, right, it does exactly the same, it's just that it is *cleaner*, I would say, that's all.

Comment: It worked, but now I wonder. Is it possible to use '#' + $hash to select the div and use .fadeIn() on it then if the value of $hash changes the previous one would fade out and let the other one fade in. The sudden jump is really annoying.

Comment: That might warrant a new question all together as I sense there is a bit more to this than fits in the comments...

Comment: Okay. I'll do that then. Thanks for your help anyways :)